# C- Memory leak, why?

Tags: c, memory-leaks, malloc, free

I found the following functions with `valgrind` me that tells me:

```
  LEAK SUMMARY:
 ==3120==    definitely lost: 7,968 bytes in 377 blocks
 ==3120==    indirectly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
 ==3120==      possibly lost: 1,904 bytes in 7 blocks
 ==3120==    still reachable: 224 bytes in 7 blocks
 ==3120==         suppressed: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
 ==3120== Reachable blocks (those to which a pointer was found) are not shown.
 ==3120== To see them, rerun with: --leak-check=full --show-leak-kinds=all
 ==3120== 
 ==3120== For counts of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -v
 ==3120== Use --track-origins=yes to see where uninitialised values come from
 ==3120== ERROR SUMMARY: 644 errors from 6 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)
```

the functions are:

```
 void put(message_t dati, op_t *err){
     message_data_t payload=dati.data;
     message_t *key1=malloc(sizeof(message_t));
    *key1=dati.hdr;
     message_data_t *malldati=(message_data_t *)malloc(sizeof(message_data_t));
     malldati->len=payload.len;
     malldati->buf=payload.buf;
     if((icl_hash_insert(hash,(void *)&key1->key,malldati))==NULL){
         *err=13;
         free(chiave);
     }else{

          *err=11;
       }
  }
```

If I add the free in the else the program don't work.

```
 void update(message_t dati, op_t *err){

     message_data_t *exist;
     message_data_t *payload=(message_data_t *) malloc(sizeof(message_data_t));
     payload=&dati.data;
     message_hdr_t key1=dati.hdr;

     exist=icl_hash_find(hash, &key1.key);

     if(exist == NULL){
         *err=20;
     }else{
        if(exist->len!=payload->len){
            *err=19;

         }else{
            exist=payload;
            *err=11;

         }
    }
 }


prototypes icl_hash_insert icl_hash_find and functions are:

icl_entry_t * icl_hash_insert(icl_hash_t *, void*, void *);

void * icl_hash_find(icl_hash_t *, void* );
```

The problem are in the key1 (put) and payload (update)
How I can fix the code?
Thanks for help!

UPDATE: Thanks for the answer, now I have another memory leak caused by the thread. `Valgrind` report:

```
 ==6111== HEAP SUMMARY:
 ==6111==     in use at exit: 1,904 bytes in 7 blocks
 ==6111==   total heap usage: 1,168 allocs, 1,161 frees, 8,042,496 bytes allocated
 ==6111== 
 ==6111== Thread 1:
 ==6111== 1,904 bytes in 7 blocks are possibly lost in loss record 1 of 1
 ==6111==    at 0x4C2FB55: calloc (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
 ==6111==    by 0x40136D4: allocate_dtv (dl-tls.c:322)
 ==6111==    by 0x40136D4: _dl_allocate_tls (dl-tls.c:539)
 ==6111==    by 0x4E422AE: allocate_stack (allocatestack.c:588)
 ==6111==    by 0x4E422AE: pthread_create@@GLIBC_2.2.5 (pthread_create.c:539)
 ==6111==    by 0x40243D: main (membox.c:642)
 ==6111== 
 ==6111== LEAK SUMMARY:
 ==6111==    definitely lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
 ==6111==    indirectly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
 ==6111==      possibly lost: 1,904 bytes in 7 blocks
 ==6111==    still reachable: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
 ==6111==         suppressed: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
 ==6111== 
 ==6111== For counts of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -v
 ==6111== Use --track-origins=yes to see where uninitialised values come from
 ==6111== ERROR SUMMARY: 641 errors from 3 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)
```

What's the problem?

Comment: The moment you did `payload=&dati.data;` in `update function` you lost memory allocate for `payload`.

Comment: At a brief glance, your whole program looks like one big memory leak. If you don't free what you allocate, you get leaks... For every call to malloc there needs to be a call to free.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has me concerned:

```
message_t *key1=malloc(sizeof(message_t));
*key1=dati.hdr;
...
if((icl_hash_insert(hash,(void *)&key1->key,malldati))==NULL){
```

You're dynamically allocating a whole new object of `message_t`, but only saving the address of one of its members.  Unless `hdr` is the first member of `message_t` and `key` is the first member of `hdr`, the address you save in the hash is *not* the same as the address of the dynamically allocated object.  That means you won't be able to `free` that memory later on.

Based on these snippets, it seems to me like you'd only want to make a copy of the *key* to save in the hash, not the entire `message_t` struct, like so:

```
T *key1 = malloc( sizeof *key1 ); // replace T with the actual key type
*key1 = dati.hdr.key;
...
if(( icl_hash_insert( hash, key1, malldati )) == NULL ){
```

I'm assuming that keys and data items are `free`d when they are removed from the hash.

Comment: thaks for help! 
no memory leaks!

Comment: but i other memory leakes caused by the thread, i have edit the post

Answer (score 0):

For every `malloc` you need to `free` once.

In `put`: You need to `free` `key1` just before `put` ends.

In `update`: You need to `free` `payload` just before `updates` ends.

Also:  `payload=&dati.data; // you set payload to point to a new address, memory will be lost`

```
void put(message_t dati, op_t *err){
     message_data_t payload=dati.data;
     message_t *key1=malloc(sizeof(message_t));
    *key1=dati.hdr;
     message_data_t *malldati=(message_data_t *)malloc(sizeof(message_data_t));
     malldati->len=payload.len;
     malldati->buf=payload.buf;
     if((icl_hash_insert(hash,(void *)&key1->key,malldati))==NULL){
         *err=13;
         free(chiave);
     }else{

          *err=11;
       }
       free(key1);
       free(malldati);
  }


void update(message_t dati, op_t *err){

     message_data_t *exist;
     message_data_t *payload=(message_data_t *) malloc(sizeof(message_data_t));
     payload=&dati.data; // you set payload to point to a new address, memory will be lost 
     message_hdr_t key1=dati.hdr;

     exist=icl_hash_find(hash, &key1.key);

     if(exist == NULL){
         *err=20;
     }else{
        if(exist->len!=payload->len){
            *err=19;

         }else{
            exist=payload;
            *err=11;

         }
    }
    free(payload);
 }
```

Comment: if i use the free at the end of the function i have a error: 00bf8000-00c19000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0                                  [heap]
7f4e3c000000-7f4e3c021000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7f4e3c021000-7f4e40000000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0 
7f4e44000000-7f4e44021000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7f4e44021000-7f4e48000000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0 
7f4e48d37000-7f4e48d4d000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 15205453                   /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1
7f4e48d4d000-7f4e48f4c000 ---p 00016000 08:01 15205453                   /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1

Comment: Please specify which function and what kind of error you are receiving?

Comment: `malldati` is being added to the hash structure, so he should *not* `free` it before the function exits.  `key1` is a bit more problematic.

Comment: @JohnBode Thank you. I just updated my post. Also found a mistake in code.